# How can I get the last updated date from one-to-many relationship table in index view on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner on rails and currently working on my class project.  I have a lead and a lead_comments table, lead has_many lead_comments and lead_comment belong_to lead, which I got those established.

In my lead's index view, I need to display the most recent lead_comments' date.  That means if the lead has 3 comments, it will only show the date of the last comment it creates in the system.  I'm aware of rails automatically created two date attributes, created_at and updated_at, and I am currently trying to figure it out how to implement this with the updated_at date.  Please help me and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out how to get the result of what I wanted.

```
Model.maximum(:updated_at)
```

This will only return the last updated_at date.